# Specify Redactor config in migration

Tags: craft3, redactor, php

is it possible to specify the Redactor config file when creating a Redactor field programmatically?

I was hoping I could do something like the following but have had no success:

```
$bodyField = $fields>createField([
    'type' => 'craft\\redactor\\Field',
    'groupId' => 1,
    'name' => 'Body',
    'handle' => 'body',
    'settings' => [
       'redactorConfig' => 'Simple.json'
    ]
]);

$fields->saveField($bodyField);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to follow up on this for anyone else who might encounter the same issue.

My problem was trying to set the redactor config within a programatically generated Matrix field.

In this case you need to use the `typesettings` keyword, for example:

```
$fields->createField([
        'type' => 'craft\\fields\\Matrix',
        'groupId' => 1,
        'name' => 'Content Builder',
        'handle' => 'contentBuilder',
        'blockTypes' => [
            'new1' => [
                'name' => 'Text Block',
                'handle' => 'textBlock',
                'instructions' => 'A rich text content block',
                'fields' => [
                    'new1' => [
                        'type' => 'craft\\redactor\\Field',
                        'name' => 'Rich Text',
                        'handle' => 'richText',                            
                        'typesettings' => [
                            'redactorConfig' => 'Simple.json'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
       ]
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should take a look what the function [createField](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-fields.html#createField()-detail) does

> Creates a field with a given config.
>
> return    [craft\base\FieldInterface](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-base-fieldinterface.html)  The field

It only creates a PHP object but does not save the field at all.

```
Craft::$app->getFields()->saveField($field);
```

is what you want

This is what the `FieldsController` does to store a new field

```
public function actionSaveField()
{
    $this->requirePostRequest();

    $fieldsService = Craft::$app->getFields();
    $request = Craft::$app->getRequest();
    $type = $request->getRequiredBodyParam('type');

    $field = $fieldsService->createField([
        'type' => $type,
        'id' => $request->getBodyParam('fieldId'),
        'groupId' => $request->getRequiredBodyParam('group'),
        'name' => $request->getBodyParam('name'),
        'handle' => $request->getBodyParam('handle'),
        'instructions' => $request->getBodyParam('instructions'),
        'translationMethod' => $request->getBodyParam('translationMethod', Field::TRANSLATION_METHOD_NONE),
        'translationKeyFormat' => $request->getBodyParam('translationKeyFormat'),
        'settings' => $request->getBodyParam('types.'.$type),
    ]);

    if (!$fieldsService->saveField($field)) {
        Craft::$app->getSession()->setError(Craft::t('app', 'Couldn’t save field.'));

        // Send the field back to the template
        Craft::$app->getUrlManager()->setRouteParams([
            'field' => $field
        ]);

        return null;
    }

    Craft::$app->getSession()->setNotice(Craft::t('app', 'Field saved.'));

    return $this->redirectToPostedUrl($field);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response; I understand how to create and save fields. This question is related to specifying the config file when creating a Redactor field.

Comment: When I copy your code into my project everything works fine. I can define whatever redactor config I want. So I thought you are missing the line. Does your field validation fail? Most questions of these type can be solved by looking at the errors

Comment: Thanks for checking this out; I tried it again with fresh install and simple migration, and everything worked great. Appreciate the help!